# datatables initialized using angular and customizing the toolbar

Tags: angularjs, datatables

http://jsfiddle.net/N7Bws/2

```
    $scope.overrideOptions = {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "iCookieDuration": 2419200, /* 1 month */
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sDom":'<"toolbar"lfrtip>'
    };


   angular.element('div.toolbar').html('foo');
```

i can't seem to customize the toolbar using this implementation. could someone point out what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your append code in controller. It needs to be done in directive, after plugn creates the toolbar.

```
// apply the plugin
var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);
/* now can add to toolbar*/
$('.dataTables_wrapper .toolbar').prepend('<div>Toolbar insert</div>');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Bws/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: there are also options to add elements to toolbar using `sDom` config in plugin. I've done what you are doing before though also. Simpler to figure out

Comment: you mean beyond the standard examples from their site?

Comment: yes...once you figure out the syntax, can add elements....has always been a bit coonfusing to me...so I find it simpler doing it with own code like you startd with